# Can I fetch only todos updated since some datetime?

Tags: php, basecamp

I get the projects, then todolists for each project and then todos for each todolist.
I want to lower resourse using for both your api and my app. So my question: Can I get only todos updated since some datetime?
PS Sorry for my english

Comment: This is a general programming Q&A site, yet you appear to be addressing a product vendor?

Comment: This is a general Q&A site. That's why the Basecamp guys decided to write the following: "To talk with us and other developers about the API, post a question on StackOverflow tagged basecamp or open a support ticket." I can't understand why you want to close this question. Leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I get only todos updated since some datetime?

Only by fetching the full list and reducing the list by comparing the created_at key to your desired datetime value.